# Passing data between ObjectClass and ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, protocols

I am trying to pass some data back to my view controller from an object class.

This is a basic over view of what classes and views are doing, and then I will show you my code.

So ViewController, loads its tableviewcells. Then inside this delegate method it calles a connection class I have created, inside that conection class is NSURLConnection methods connecting and downloading data from the database, in the connectionDidFinishLoading method of this connection class I set up a parsing class and pass all of the downloaded data over to that.
Then I parse that data, and at the end of that parser inside parserDidEndDocument, I am trying to send the data that is now in an array variable back to my view controller to display. However.. for some reason my protocols and delegates are not working.
I have set up protocols inside m parser class and set the delegates in my view controller but it never makes it to my protocol method.

I will show you my code below.

parserclass.h

```
@protocol PassParsedData <NSObject>
@required
- (void)sendManufactureArray:(NSArray *)array;
@end
//..
id <PassParsedData> delegate;
//..
@property (strong) id delegate;
//
```

parserclass.m

```
#import "VehicleSearchViewController.h"
//..
@synthesize delegate;
//..


- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    //.. array stuff is set up and i can log it so i know its working.. i just want to show you the protocol and delegate stuff to be clear
    [[self delegate]sendManufactureArray:filteredArray];
}
```

Then moving onto my view controller where I am hoping to call the protocol and get the filteredArray data back.

ViewController.h

```
#import "EngineResponses.h" //delegates & protocols
//..
@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <PassParsedData> {
//..
```

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import "EngineResponses.h"
//..
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
//..
parserClass *pc = [[parserClass alloc] init];
    [pc setDelegate:self];
//..
}

- (void)sendManufactureArray:(NSArray *)array //Breakpoint here is never accessed
{
    FilterArray = array;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

As you can see in that last method which is the protocol I am calling, its never accessed by the thread. I have checked, This call

```
[[self delegate]sendManufactureArray:filteredArray];
```

gets accessed fine.. but it just never makes it back to the View Controller.. any ideas... am I missing anything? .. im at a complete loss, been working on this all day.

any help would be HUGELY appreciated! :)

UPDATE:

I have added this to my ViewController.h

```
//..
ParserClass *parserclass;
//..
@property (strong, nonatomic) ParserClass *parserclass;
//..
```

viewcontroller.m

```
@synthesize parserclass;
//..
//then I call this in viewdidload
[engineResponses setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: have you tried making the parserClass a universal variable instead of local to viewdidload?

Comment: Like Eric said, unless im missunderstanding the concept of arc, your pc class is only living troughout the viewdidload method, even tho you set the delegate as strong, the pc instance has a strong link to the viewcontroller but not the otherway arround so as soon as the viewdid load finishes all the properties in the pc class are nil and the arc thing will dispose of it.

Comment: I have added MyClass *myclass; etc into the header of ViewController and @synthesized it.. then I have called [myclass setDelegate:self]; and still it is not making it to the -(void)sendManufactureArray... method thats in the viewcontroller.... :(

Comment: I have updated my question.. to check to see if I cam creating a global valu.

Comment: This line [engineResponses setDelegate:self], should it be self.parserclass.delegate = self?  Assuming that you have also instantiated the parseclass instant in viewDidload as well.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in the comments, your `pc` variable is being deallocated at the end of the `viewDidLoad` block, since the only reference it has goes out of scope there.  If you want it to live on, you must enlarge its scope (i.e. make it an instance variable).

Comment: right. so thats creating the **@property (strong, nonatomic) MyClass *myclass;** etc then synthesizing it?

Comment: so I have made it a global variable.. but its still not solving the problem.. this is a really sticky issue...

Comment: you dont need to make it a property but add it to the variable list in your .h file.  Add that variable in the curly brace section after your @interface and assign to that instead of declaring pc inside the viewDidLoad method.